# is it possible that a variable have the type of an interface in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, object, kotlin, interface

```
private lateinit var show:ShowUsersMain
```

what does that even mean? I saw this in someone's code
the `ShowUsersMain` is an interface which looks like this

```
interface ShowUsersMain :BaseShowList { 
fun getListUsers(users:List<usersApp>)
fun showError()
}
```

as I know interfaces can not be instantiated but now the `show` looks like an object of the `ShowUsersMain` interface to me, so I got confused.

Comment: Yes it's normal, one of the principles of objective programming. Basically an interface is a contract for a class that says I override this set of method(s). Someone doesn't care what's behind the object assigned to that var but he demands that this object will be implementing ShowUsersMain interface.

Comment: but there are many resources that deny the possibility of instantiating interfaces can you give me a document that explains it?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, interfaces can not be instantiated, but objects which implemnent this interface can, and similarily such objects references can be assigned to a variable of the interface type.

```
class ShowUserFragment: Fragment(), ShowUsersMain {
   override fun getListUsers(users:List<usersApp>) { ... }
   override fun fun showError() { ... }
}
private lateinit var show: ShowUsersMain = ShowUserFragment()
show.showError() // OK
show.onResume() // NO
(show as Fragment).onResume() // OK
```

When referred to by show, you can only call 2 interface functions, and can not call Fragment's methods.

Comment: alright but the case is different as you see he straightly instantiated the interface not a class or an activity which implements from it. Im trying to find out how did he do that.

Comment: Nobody can instantiate an interface.  Somewhere in the code, there's an instantiation of a class that gets assigned to `show`.

Comment: How about instantiating an anonymous class? It can look and feel like what you are talking about.

`show = object : ShowUsersMain {
   override fun getListUsers(users:List<usersApp>) { ... }
   override fun fun showError() { ... }`